# Color and syntax theme issue in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am unable to apply color and syntax setting. Can someone please suggest me the correct way?

Created these directories in `/home/ec2-user` directory.

```
mkdir ~/.vim
mkdir ~/.vim/colors
mkdir ~/.vim/syntax
```

Added `php.vim` in syntax and `wombat256.vim` in colors directory.

`vimrc` file is present in `/etc` directory.

```
:colorscheme wombat256.vim
E185: Cannot find color scheme wombat256.vim
```

I am following instruction from [here](http://lenss.nl/2011/04/vim-for-a-php-developer/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:colorscheme wombat256
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

[lucapette gave you the correct wording](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9591442/50776) but there are still two problems with your setup:

1. All your customizations are supposed to go in your own `~/.vimrc` file. Don't touch the one found in `/etc`.
2. You don't need a separate PHP syntax file because Vim already comes with one by default.